# CQ5 Dialog not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem

I am learning CQ5 and I am stuck at creating dialog validation. My JavaScript is in the clientlibs folder and I am using a listener to call the function, but it isn't getting invoked. I see no validation.

I am trying to make the URL field required if the corresponding ID has been provided.

The following is my JS code.

```
var fieldsetCheck = {};

fieldsetCheck.chkBlankFields  = function chkBlankFields(panel) {

    var fieldSets = panel.findByType('dialogfieldset');
    var fLength = fieldSets.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < fLength; i++) {
        var fieldSet = fieldSets[i];
        var Id = panel.getComponent('Id'+(i++));
        var Url = panel.getComponent('Url'+(i++)); 

        if(Id.getValue().trim() !== ""||Url.getValue().trim()!=="") { 
            campId.allowBlank = false;
            campUrl.allowBlank = false;
        } else {
            campId.allowBlank = true;
            campUrl.allowBlank = true;
        }
    }    
}
```

and this is my dialog.xml

```
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0"zzzmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog" height="500" id="textNavEditDialog" title="Test Configuration Dialog" width="600" xtype="dialog">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <tabs jcr:primaryType="cq:TabPanel" activeTab="{Long}0" title="Test Configuration" xtype="tabpanel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <campaigns jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" title="Links" xtype="panel">
                    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                            <fieldsetDialog1 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" xtype="dialogfieldset" border="{Boolean}true" collapseFirst="{Boolean}true" collapsed="{Boolean}false" collapsible="{Boolean}false"  hideLabel="{Boolean}false" id="fieldset1">
                                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">

                                    <Id1 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldDescription="Enter segment only (exclude seg=)" fieldLabel="Segment Number 1" allowBlank="{Boolean}false" maxLength="12" name="./sc:Id1" nanText="Please enter a numeric value" xtype="numberfield" ItemId ="Id1"/>
                                    <Url1 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldDescription="Path to Campaign 1" fieldLabel="Campaign URL 1" allowBlank="{Boolean}false" name="./sc:Url1" predicate="hierarchy" suffix="/_jcr_content/par.html" typeAhead="{Boolean}false" xtype="pathfield" ItemId ="Url1"/>
                                </items>
                            </fieldsetDialog1>

                            <fieldsetDialog2 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" xtype="dialogfieldset" border="{Boolean}true" collapseFirst="{Boolean}true" collapsed="{Boolean}false" collapsible="{Boolean}false"  hideLabel="{Boolean}false" id="fieldset2">
                                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">

                                    <Id2 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldDescription="Enter segment only (exclude seg=)" fieldLabel="Segment Number 2" maxLength="12" name="./sc:Id2" nanText="Please enter a numeric value" xtype="numberfield" ItemId ="Id2"/>
                                    <Url2 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldDescription="Path to Campaign 2" fieldLabel="Campaign URL 2" name="./sc:Url2" predicate="hierarchy" suffix="/_jcr_content/par.html" typeAhead="{Boolean}false" xtype="pathfield" ItemId = "Url2" />
                                </items>

                            </fieldsetDialog2>

                            <fieldsetDialog3 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" xtype="dialogfieldset" border="{Boolean}true" collapseFirst="{Boolean}true" collapsed="{Boolean}false" collapsible="{Boolean}false"  hideLabel="{Boolean}false" id="fieldset3">
                                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">

                                    <Id3 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldDescription="Enter segment only (exclude seg=)" fieldLabel="Segment Number 3" maxLength="12" name="./sc:Id3" nanText="Please enter a numeric value" xtype="numberfield" ItemId ="Id3" />
                                    <Url3 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldDescription="Path to Campaign 3" fieldLabel="Campaign URL 3" name="./sc:Url3" predicate="hierarchy" suffix="/_jcr_content/par.html" typeAhead="{Boolean}false" xtype="pathfield" ItemId ="Url3"/>
                                </items>
                            </fieldsetDialog3>
                    </items>
                    <listeners jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" beforesubmit="function(this) { fieldsetCheck.chkBlankFields(this);}" />
                </campaigns>
            </items>
        </tabs>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Comment: JavaScript is not Java, so I've removed the [tag:java] tag from your post.

Comment: Thank you!!! Thought that CQ5 has Java framework and its relevant

Answer (score 0):

[Panel](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/output/CQ.Ext.Panel.html) xtype has no beforesubmit event. That event is only available for [dialog](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/output/CQ.Dialog.html) xtype. The listener will have to be a child node of the dialog node.

The function will be invoked with dialog as parameter and not panel. Since your using findByType() method in your function it'll still work , just renaming the variable to dialog for readability should do.

Comment: Sorry didnt get this part "just renaming the variable to dialog for readability should do."

Comment: @maddy since the variable is actually references a dialog and not panel , it'd be better to call it dialog. Might confuse someone else if they trying to maintain the code

Comment: I tried based on your comments, it shows me l.fireFn.apply is not a function error. please guide

Comment: @maddy , panel.getComponent('Id'+(i++)); is wrong the result is Id0 . Change it to panel.getComponent('Id'+(i+1));

Answer (score 0):

What I see, there is problem in incrementing the id and url as there is i++ in both the statement leading in 2 extra increment in each iteration so in the second iteration the value will be 3 instead of 1 and so on. so, i suggest the following code

```
  for (var i = 0; i < fLength; i++) 
  {
        var fieldSet = fieldSets[i];
        var Id = panel.getComponent('Id'+(i + 1));
        var Url = panel.getComponent('Url'+(i + 1)); 

        if(Id.getValue().trim() !== ""||Url.getValue().trim()!=="")
        { 
            campId.allowBlank = false;
            campUrl.allowBlank = false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            campId.allowBlank = true;
            campUrl.allowBlank = true;
        }
  }
```